# Performance Improvement of AIX application.

Tags: performance, aix

I want improve the performance of application running of aix operating system.

please find the details about the application below.

1. Application coded in c/c++.
2. The code is compiled by the gcc  version 4.2.4 compiler.
3. The operation system version is AIX 6.1

please suggest some sources for performance tweaks in code  and operating system settings.

note: The cpu usage of the application is very low mostly it is around 30-40.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start by (a) defining your performance requirements and (b) profiling the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Paul's suggestions - what compiler options are you currently using with gcc/g++? Specifically do the list of compiler options include the -O or -O2 or -O3 ? If not, these would be the easiest way to quickly improve the performance of your application. More information on gcc Optimization Options can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

When performance is important, you may want to also consider using IBM's [XL C/C++ for AIX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/xlcpp/aix/) compiler which will generally generate better performing code than gcc.